# How to see changes made to buttons in react without having to refresh page?

Tags: reactjs, button, state, refresh, disable

I have a series of buttons mapped from an API list. When pressed, the buttons change a users rank value. however I want it so that a user can not assign a lower rank than the one they currently have, so I have made it so that the buttons disable if the key value is lower than the current rank key value. the functionality works, however you only see the buttons become disabled if you refresh the page.

```
export default class rankChangeButtons extends React.Component{
  
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        rankId: this.props.rankId,
        rank: this.props.rank,
        
      }

      this.updateRank = this.updateRank.bind(this);
    }

getData = () => {
    //this is where I call the API 
    data: res.data
    }

updateRank(element) { 
      const { id, value } = element.target; 
      let headers: any = {"rankingList": this.props.rankingListId, "Content-Type" : "application/json"};
      var payload = {"rankId":id,"affiliationId":this.props.affiliationId};
      
      saveRankChange(payload, headers).then(()=>{
        //call buttonAction function on parent component.
        this.props.buttonAction(
          id, value
        )
        //id and value are passed to parent to update rank
      }).catch((e: any)=>{})
    }



render() { 
      return(
        <div> 
          <h5>User Rank:</h5> 
          <div className='buttonContainer'>
            {this.state.data.map((rank =>  
                <li key={rank.key}>
                  <button id={rank.key} value = {rank.text} onClick={this.updateRank} disabled={rank.key <= this.state.rankId ? true : false}>
                    {rank.text}
                  </button>
                </li>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
          
        )
            
      }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to see which buttons are disabled after changing the value without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Try to use `event.preventDefault( )` to avoid page refreshing.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your comment. My problem isn't that the page is automatically refreshing. it's that I have to refresh the page to see the updates made to the button. I want to see the updates when they happen.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `this.updateRank` is changing states?
Because according to react docs, if there's a state change, then the render method is called again with this.state updated.

You could see the button getting disabled if one of these options actually happened:

- `this.updateRank` updates this.state.rankId.
- `this.updateRank` calls a function that changes the property `rank` on the item you need on `this.state.data`.

If everything is fine, then show us `this.updateRank` code or how exactly the update happens.

Comment: I have updated the original post, I hope that adds some more context.