# How to make button change on click without having to refresh page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have pairs of "yes" "no" buttons that were not changing color onClick unless I refreshed the page. My bandaid solution was to add `refresh()` to `handleClick` which forces a full page refresh every time a button is clicked. While this does change the color of the button, I would much prefer the page not having to refresh and load at the top after every button click, and each button seamlessly changes color when clicked.

I have tried to use `e.preventDefault()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533514/how-to-see-changes-made-to-buttons-in-react-without-having-to-refresh-page) to also prevent the full page refresh but I'm not sure of where or how to use it in my case as I am not passing an event to the handler.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Button
    style={{ margin: '0px 5px' }}
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() =>
      handleClick(row.insight_id, row.device_id, 1)
    }
    color={
      row.userConfirmed == null
        ? 'default'
        : row.userConfirmed === 1
        ? 'primary'
        : 'default'
    }
  >
     Yes
  </Button>
   <Button
    style={{ margin: '0px 5px' }}
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() =>
      handleClick(row.insight_id, row.device_id, 0)
    }
    color={
      row.userConfirmed == null
        ? 'default'
        : row.userConfirmed === 1
        ? 'default'
        : 'primary'
    }
  >
    No
  </Button>
</React.Fragment>
```

```
 const handleClick = (insightId, deviceId, value) => {
    dispatch(updateUserConfirm(insightId, deviceId, value));
    refresh();
  };
```

[image]

EDIT: Addition of reducer & where `row` comes from

```
const userInsightsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
.
.
. 
case UPDATE_USER_CONFIRM_BEGIN:
      return {

        ...state,
        result: 'BEGINNING',
      };
    case UPDATE_USER_CONFIRM_SUCCESS:
      const userInsightsDataNew = state.userInsightsData
      const insightIndex = state.userInsightsData.findIndex(insight => insight.device_id === action.payload.deviceId && insight.insight_id === action.payload.insightId )
      const updatedInsight = {...state.userInsightsData[insightIndex], userConfirmed:action.payload.value}
      userInsightsDataNew[insightIndex] = updatedInsight
      return {
        ...state,
        userInsightsData : userInsightsDataNew,
        result: "SUCCESS",
      };
    case UPDATE_USER_CONFIRM_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        result: 'FAILURE',
```

```
        let row = userInsights.userInsightsData[index];
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the reducer that's connected to `dispatch(updateUserConfirm(insightId, deviceId, value));`, and we'll need to see where `row` comes from.

Comment: If these are in a form, just make the button `type='button'` (or perhaps do that anyway) since the default is submit

Comment: @NicholasTower you got it, added to the edit.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss These buttons are a part of a table rather than a form, but I'll give that a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked on it and this was the best solution for me:

```
                              <Button
                                style={{ margin: '0px 5px' }}
                                variant="contained"
                                onClick={() => {
                                  handleClick(row.insight_id, row.device_id, 1);
                                  row.userConfirmed = 1;
                                }}
                                color={
                                  row.userConfirmed == null
                                    ? 'default'
                                    : row.userConfirmed === 1
                                    ? 'primary'
                                    : 'default'
                                }
                              >
                                Yes
                              </Button>

                              <Button
                                style={{ margin: '0px 5px' }}
                                variant="contained"
                                onClick={() => {
                                  handleClick(row.insight_id, row.device_id, 0);
                                  row.userConfirmed = 0;
                                }}
                                color={
                                  row.userConfirmed == null
                                    ? 'default'
                                    : row.userConfirmed === 1
                                    ? 'default'
                                    : 'primary'
                                }
                              >
                                No
                              </Button>
```

I kept onClick event handlers for each button that updates the `row.userConfirmed` value (used to determine the color of the buttons).

I'm still using `handleClick` to dispatch an action to update the data in my state, and then using the updated data to set the right colors of the buttons when I come back to the page.

```
 const handleClick = (insightId, deviceId, value) => {
    dispatch(updateUserConfirm(insightId, deviceId, value));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to render the component, you have to use useState hook, define a state variable and when you click on a button, change the state so that the component renders and keeps the state value as the color you want it to change to.

Comment: Perhaps update with some code to illustrate what you suggest here?

Comment: whats the row object here..is it a state or just a prop?or if the values are getting from a reducer,you can dispatch an action to that reducer.It would be great if you describe it more.

Comment: @gnanasaiDachiraju thank you for the suggestion, I've added an edit to the post for more information on the reducer and where `row` comes from